# How to install kubectl and helm using dockerfile?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to Docker. I'm trying to create a dockerfile which basically sets kubectl (Kubernetes client), helm 3 and Python 3.7. I used:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY ./ /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to add `kubectl` and `helm`. What would be the best way to install those two?

Comment: Do you mind adding a bit of context around best? Are you trying to keep versions at a specific point or always use latest? Are you trying to find the slimmest image? I usually pull latest like this but it kind of depends on your use case.

Comment: @JasonMorgan latest probably will do the job for me. I can always replace it with `$K8S_VERSION` no?

Answer (score 14):

Working Dockerfile. This will install the latest and stable versions of `kubectl` and `helm-3`

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY ./ /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add curl openssl bash --no-cache
RUN curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" \
    && chmod +x ./kubectl \
    && mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
    && curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3 \
    && chmod +x get_helm.sh && ./get_helm.sh
```

Comment: Shell scripts from that source don't run in alpine images

Answer (score 1):

Python should be available from a python base image I guess.
My take would be s.th like

```
ENV K8S_VERSION=v1.18.X
ENV HELM_VERSION=v3.X.Y
ENV HELM_FILENAME=helm-${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

and then in the Dockerfile

```
RUN curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${K8S_VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl -o /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
 && curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/${HELM_FILENAME} | tar xz && mv linux-amd64/helm /bin/helm && rm -rf linux-amd64
```

But be aware of the availability of curl or wget in the baseimage, maybe these or other tools and programs have to be installed before you can use it in the Dockerfile. This always depends on the baseimage used

Comment: FYI, the referenced helm URL is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

This Dockerfile worked for me with an ubuntu base. I needed kubectl and helm to work with the rest of the deps I had in my docker image

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends ...
RUN curl -LO https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.24.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3 && \
    chmod 700 get-helm-3 &&\
    ./get-helm-3
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
FROM amd64/python:3.11.3-alpine

RUN apk add build-base
RUN apk add curl
# Install kubectl
RUN curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s 
    https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
RUN curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/$(curl -L -s 
    https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl.sha256"
RUN install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

# Install helm
RUN curl -LO https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.7.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf helm-v3.7.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
    mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm && \
    rm -rf helm-v3.7.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz linux-amd64
```